# Dummy subfigure label without changing anything to the caption formatting

Tags: subcaption, cleveref

I want to use *cleveref* to reference to panels inside a figure. Thereby I design the entire figure outside *LaTeX* with labels *a*, *b*, ... for the different panels. To this end I need some dummy subfigures with labels. So what I did was:

```
\documentclass[prl,twocolumn]{revtex4-2}

\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

See \cref{fig:1:a}

\begin{figure}
    \begin{subfigure}{\textwidth} % this 'subfigure' env. has no visible content
        \refstepcounter{subfigure}\label{fig:1:a}
        \refstepcounter{subfigure}\label{fig:1:b}
    \end{subfigure}%
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=.5\textwidth]{example-image}
    \caption{(a) First sub caption. (b) Second sub caption. And some more text}
    \label{fig:1}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Which gives (zoom):

[image]

The problem is however that *subcaption* changes the formatting of the caption. For completeness, without the `subfigure` and without including *subcaption* the caption looked like this (zoom):

[image]

Since I do not use the subcaptions for anythings else then a dummy label I do not want to change the formatting of the my caption at all.

So my question is simple: How do I get dummy subcaption labels without the *subcaption* package?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answers (2) by @Simon Dispa suggests using the `subfig` package. It turns out that it has the option:

```
\usepackage[caption=false]{subfig}
```

According to the manual this is what I need:

> For compatibility with other packages which modify the caption and where the stan- dard caption package whould interfere with the desired layout, the caption package has a special option, `caption=false`, which loads the internals (i.e., the "kernel" caption3 package) without modifying the `\caption` command.

Indeed, in a real example:

```tex
\documentclass[prl,twocolumn]{revtex4-2}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[caption=false]{subfig}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\usepackage{kantlipsum}

\begin{document}
    \maketitle

    See \cref{fig:1a} and  subfigure~\subref{fig:1b}.
    \begin{figure}[ht!]
        \subfloat{\label{fig:1a}}
        \subfloat{\label{fig:1b}}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}
        \caption{
            \protect\subref{fig:1a} First sub caption.
            \protect\subref{fig:1b} Second sub caption.
            \kant[8]}
       \label{fig:1}
    \end{figure}

    \kant[1-7]
\end{document}
```

the results looks like what I would expect:
[image]

Indeed, without `subfig` the formatting is the same:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Option **(1)** Use  `\captionsetup[figure]{...}` to get back the right format.

[image: d]

```
    \documentclass[prl,twocolumn]{revtex4-2}

\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\captionsetup[figure]{textfont=normalfont,singlelinecheck=off,justification=raggedright}% added <<<

\usepackage{kantlipsum}
\begin{document}
    \maketitle
    
    See \cref{fig:1a}
    
    \begin{figure}[ht]
        \begin{subfigure}{\textwidth} % this 'subfigure' env. has no visible content
            \refstepcounter{subfigure}\label{fig:1a}
            \refstepcounter{subfigure}\label{fig:1b}
        \end{subfigure}%
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}% use linewidth <<<
        %\caption{(a) First sub caption. (b) Second sub caption. And some more text}
            \caption{ (\protect\subref{fig:1a}) First sub caption.  (\protect\subref{fig:1b}) Second sub caption. And some more text}
        \label{fig:1}
    \end{figure}

    \kant[1-7]
\end{document}
```

or **(2)** Instead of `subcaption` it can be used `subfig`. (See the use of `\subref{..}` in the example)

[image: c]

```
\documentclass[prl,twocolumn]{revtex4-2}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\usepackage{kantlipsum}

\captionsetup[figure]{textfont=normalfont,singlelinecheck=off,justification=raggedright}

\begin{document}
    \maketitle
    
    See \cref{fig:1a} and  subfigure~\subref{fig:1b}.   
    \begin{figure}[ht!]
        \subfloat{\label{fig:1a}}
        \subfloat{\label{fig:1b}}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{FigureOne.pdf}
        \caption{ \protect\subref{fig:1a} First sub caption.  \protect\subref{fig:1b} Second sub caption. And some more text}
       \label{fig:1}
    \end{figure}
    
    \kant[1-7]
\end{document}
```

The `FigureOne.pdf` was generated by this file.

```
%%file FigureOne.tex

\documentclass[preview, border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
    
    \begin{figure}
    \centering
    \subfloat[][]{\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{example-image-a}}\enspace
    \subfloat[][]{\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{example-image-b}}
\end{figure}    
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the solutions. I like solution 2 because it simplifies the dummy labels a lot. However... neither are a solution of the problem ;). Using *subfig*, like *subcaption*, modifies the `captionsetup`, which in this answer is then re-modified by hand. The problem is that it does not correspond to the style given by the `cls`. Mostly though, an elegant solution would be to have a solution that simply does not touch the `captionsetup` at all.

Comment: @Tom de Geus Customizing the caption style for figures and table is standard practice after loading the package `caption`. In the same way we specify the dimensions of the page after loading  `geometry`. After all, it is unreasonable for the default settings coincide or automatically adjust to our wishes.

Comment: I can very much agree to it. However, I am looking to respect a prescribed style and not looking to approximate it afterwards. So my question is not so much to get a 'fix' (or work-around), but to elegantly solve this problem no matter if I change the `cls` with specifies a different style.